# I am able to retrieve Firebase data but can not add to ArrayList

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: FIREBASE DATABASE]

I am able to read data from Firebase but when i try to add value (Item) to ArrayList, the item is `null` value..

`MainActivity.java`

```
1    package com.example.digesh.divinecart; 
2     
3    import android.os.Bundle; 
4    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
5    import android.widget.GridView; 
6     
7    import com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener; 
8    import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot; 
9    import com.firebase.client.Firebase; 
10   import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError; 
11   import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase; 
12    
13   import java.util.ArrayList; 
14    
15   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
16    
17       Item i = new Item(); 
18       GridView gridView; 
19       ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>(); 
20       itemAdapter itemadapter; 
21       FirebaseDatabase database; 
22       //DatabaseReference mRef; 
23       Firebase mRef; 
24    
25       @Override 
26       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
27           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
28           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
29           Firebase.setAndroidContext(this); 
30    
31           //mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); 
32    
33           //mRef = database.getReference(); 
34           mRef = new Firebase("https://divinecart-9b58e.firebaseio.com/"); 
35    
36    
37          /* mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { 
38               @Override 
39               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
40                   itemName = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class); 
41                   name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name); 
42                   name1.setText(itemName); 
43    
44               } 
45    
46               @Override 
47               public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { 
48    
49               } 
50           });*/ 
51    
52    
53           gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview); 
54    
55    
56           // itemAdapter itemadapter = new itemAdapter(MainActivity.this,image,itemName,itemPrice); 
57           itemadapter = new itemAdapter(MainActivity.this, getItems()); 
58    
59    
60           gridView.setAdapter(itemadapter); 
61           /*gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 
62               @Override 
63               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) { 
64                   //String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); 
65                   Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),itemdetails.class); 
66                   i.putExtra("Position",position); 
67                   startActivity(i); 
68    
69                   //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),itemName[position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
70                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),itemName[position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
71    
72               } 
73           });*/ 
74       } 
75    
76       public void fetchData(DataSnapshot ds) { 
77           items.clear(); 
78    
79           for (DataSnapshot data : ds.getChildren()) { 
80               //i = new Item(); 
81               //i = data.getValue(Item.class); 
82               i = (Item) data.getValue(Item.class); 
83               //i = (Item)data.getValue(Item.class); 
84    
85    
86               items.add(i); 
87               //System.out.println(i.getName()); 
88               //items.add(i.getName().toString(),i.getPrice().toString()); 
89           } 
90           itemadapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
91    
92       } 
93    
94       public ArrayList<Item> getItems() { 
95           mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() { 
96               @Override 
97               public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) { 
98    
99                   fetchData(dataSnapshot); 
100                  itemadapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
101              } 
102   
103              @Override 
104              public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { 
105   
106                  fetchData(dataSnapshot); 
107                  itemadapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
108   
109              } 
110   
111              @Override 
112              public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
113   
114              } 
115   
116              @Override 
117              public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { 
118   
119              } 
120   
121              @Override 
122              public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { 
123   
124              } 
125          }); 
126          return items; 
127      } 
128   
129   
130  } 
131
```

`Item.java`

```
1    package com.example.digesh.divinecart; 
2     
3    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties; 
4     
5    /** 
6     * Created by Digesh on 26-10-16. 
7     */ 
8    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) 
9    public class Item { 
10       //private int image; 
11       private String name; 
12       private String price; 
13    
14       public Item() { 
15    
16    
17       } 
18    
19       public Item(String name, String price){ 
20           //this.image = image; 
21           super(); 
22           this.name = name; 
23           this.price = price; 
24    
25       } 
26    
27    
28    
29       /* public int getImage(){ 
30               return image; 
31           } 
32           public void setImage(int image){ 
33               this.image = image; 
34           } 
35       */ 
36       public String getName(){ 
37           return name; 
38       } 
39       public void setName(String name){ 
40           this.name = name; 
41       } 
42    
43       public String getPrice(){ 
44           return price; 
45       } 
46       public void setPrice(String price){ 
47           this.price = price; 
48       } 
49   } 
50
```

Comment: What is the problem? `(Item) data.getValue(Item.class);` returns null?

Comment: yes...  i = (Item) data.getValue(Item.class); is null. i can see corrent data in snapshot.. but i is null...

Comment: Okay, well, we cannot see your Firebase data, so something about `data.getValue` is not correctly mapping your Snapshot data to your Java object

Comment: i can send you pic of my database, but i do not not how to send it here. so can you please give me your email.. so i can do

Comment: Sorry, cannot do. Please [edit] your post and use the provided image attachment features.

Comment: Please try to keep caps lock off

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you initially used the new 9.x.x SDK and then commented most of that code out and are now using the legacy 2.5.x SDK.  But you must have left references to the new SDK, such as `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'`, in your build.gradle file, because your code contains a declaration of `com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase`.  The legacy SDK and new SDK are not compatible and cannot be used in the same build.  That may be the cause of the problem you are observing.  Choose one SDK or the other and update your build.gradle and code to use only one.  See the [Firebase Upgrade Guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in your Item class. The values you request must match up to the values in your database perfectly, the class should be changed as follows

```
public class Item { 
10       //private int image; 
11       private String itemName; 
12       private String itemPrice; 
13    
14       public Item() { 
15    
16    
17       } 
18    
19       public Item(String itemName, String itemPrice){ 
20           //this.image = image; 
21           super(); 
22           this.itemName = itemName; 
23           this.itemPrice = itemPrice; 
24    
25       } 
26    
27    
28    
29       /* public int getImage(){ 
30               return image; 
31           } 
32           public void setImage(int image){ 
33               this.image = image; 
34           } 
35       */ 
36       public String getItemName(){ 
37           return itemName; 
38       } 
39       public void setName(String name){ 
40           this.itemName = itemName; 
41       } 
42    
43       public String getItemPrice(){ 
44           return itemPrice; 
45       } 
46       public void setItemPrice(String itemPrice){ 
47           this.itemPrice = itemPrice; 
48       } 
49   }
```

That should make the data snapshot work. When that Item Class is pulling data from the database the names must be exactly the same so it knows what to pull.

Comment: Item i = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Item.class);
             String fname = i.itemName;
                    String fprice = "Rs. "+i.itemPrice;

                    items.add(new Item(fname,fprice));